# Why would an invocation name for an AoG app be ignored?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have an Actions On Google app in testing. Most of the time when I say, "OK Google talk to 'my app name here'" my app runs. Sometimes it does not and Google passes the question to Google Search. Then, on my phone I will get search results in the Google app; on the simulator I will see a message like "blah blah blah not supported in simulation".

I have had the question up since last week on the official Google plus "support" page with only a single reply asking if the screen shots were real or not from a person whom I think is just another developer.

[successful invocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z8i7.png)
[Unsuccessful invocation handled by search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlMjj.png)

[The screenshots were captured and NOT drawn by the way]

Does anyone here have an idea why search is run and what I can do about it if anything?

This is a hobby project of mine to be sure, but if I were trying to speech enable a device it seems to me that this might be a showstopper and a reason to go with another vendor. No?

Answer (score 0):

Just from those screen shots, my first thought is "how is 'visor' pronounced"? And how could it sound like you're mispronouncing it? If it doesn't recognize the "visor" part to match the pronunciation that you think it should be getting, even if the word displayed is the same, it might be passing it along to search to handle.

Remember - this is English. What is written out isn't necessarily what it *sounds* like. And the system is trying to match what you *say* and not what it is written as.

One thing you can do is to listen to the recordings Google has of your invocation attempts. Try and figure out if the successful ones sound different from the ones that failed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I am not sure pronunciation is the issue for these  reasons. The actions console made me speak the word into the mic and recognize it _properly_ before it accepted it as an invocation name, the 5 letters do comprise an English word pronounced in the normal way, when recognition does fail (it sometimes hears an F rather than a V and returns Pfizer and I'm OK with that) and it sure looks like (I could be wrong) it is analyzing the query and realizes it understands and chooses to answer a query it is trained to expect. The issue is when is the invocation name ignored?